# Problema na remoção de nós numa lista

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Boa noite,

Estou a fazer um programa que é uma espécie de "candy Crush" em SDL. E precisava da vossa ajuda para me ajudarem a remover as bolas do jogo, que neste caso são os nós da lista.

O programa está a percorrer o jogo à procura dos nós que tem de remover que estão marcados com 1 no campo defenicoes.marca.

Espero que tenha sido mais especifico desta vez!!!

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Errorr: segmentaion fault (Core dumped)

```
bolhas_ligadas *remove_bolhas(bolhas_ligadas *lista,int largura,int altura){
  bolhas_ligadas *aux,*aux4;
  int i,j;
  aux=lista;
  for(j=0;j<largura;j++){

    for(i=0;i<altura;i++){

      aux4=aux->next;
      if(aux4->defenicoes.marca==1){

        aux->next=aux4->next;  
        free(aux4);   
      }

      aux=aux->next;

    }
  } 
  return lista;
}
```

Comment: Como foram estabelecidas as ligações `next` entre as várias `bolhas_ligadas` ? Coloque também essa parte na pergunta

Comment: Já tentou rodar isso com o GDB para saber exatamente a origem do `segmentaion fault (Core dumped)`? O que eu posso perceber é que você não compara se `aux` é válido durante o looping, provavelmente você esgota os elementos da lista em algum momento, e quando o looping volta ele tenta acessar área de memórias indevidas.